# How to get value json with - in karate framework Ex: Attribute auth-token

Tags: json, testing, frameworks, karate

Help with problem below

Variable:

```
* def token = loginResponse.response.data.attributes.auth-token
```

Error:

> -unknown-:7 - javascript evaluation failed: loginResponse.response.data.attributes.auth-token, ReferenceError:
>   "token" is not defined in  at line number 1
>   com.intuit.karate.exception.KarateException: -unknown-:7 - javascript
>   evaluation failed: loginResponse.response.data.attributes.auth-token,
>   ReferenceError: "token" is not defined in  at line number 1     at
>   ✽.* def token = loginResponse.response.data.attributes.auth-token
>   (-unknown-:7)

Schemma json:

```
{
"data": {
    "id": "3326",
    "type": "users",
    "attributes": {
    "email": "emerson@gmail.com",
    "auth-token": "3ve6mPU4G-txLBmvc5eJ",
    "created-at": "2020-04-19T17:30:54.031Z",
    "updated-at": "2020-04-21T17:47:39.649Z"
    }
}
}
```

Request:

```
Scenario: List tasks

Given path '/tasks'

And header Accept = " application/vnd.tasksmanager.v2"

And header Authorization = token

When method GET

Then status 200
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For special characters in JSON keys, use square-brackets to access:

```
* def token = loginResponse.response.data.attributes['auth-token']
```